# Shortcut to generate an NSRange for entire length of NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsrange

Is there a short way to say "entire string" rather than typing out:

```
NSMakeRange(0, myString.length)]
```

It seems silly that the longest part of this kind of code is the least important (because I usually want to search/replace within entire string)…

```
[myString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"replace_me"
                          withString:replacementString
                             options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                               range:NSMakeRange(0, myString.length)];
```

Comment: If you need more than 5 times, then you can make a method/category, But for under 5 time your `NSMakeRange(0, myString.length)]` will be shorter, isn't it?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Function? Category method?

```
- (NSRange)fullRange
{
    return (NSRange){0, [self length]};
}
```

---

```
[myString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"replace_me"
                          withString:replacementString
                             options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                               range:[myString fullRange]];
```

Comment: Hah. Awesome that we both named it `fullRange`, and that we both used the new compound literals, at the same time.

Comment: Indeed. And commented at the same time!

Comment: The literals work just fine, but you could also do return NSMakeRange(0, [self length]); if you wanted.

Answer (score 29):

**Swift 4+**, useful for `NSRegularExpression` and `NSAttributedString`

```
extension String {
    var nsRange : NSRange {
        return NSRange(self.startIndex..., in: self)
    }

    func range(from nsRange: NSRange) -> Range<String.Index>? {
        return Range(nsRange, in: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Not that I know of. But you could easily add an `NSString` category:

```
@interface NSString (MyRangeExtensions)
- (NSRange)fullRange
@end

@implementation NSString (MyRangeExtensions)
- (NSRange)fullRange {
  return (NSRange){0, self.length};
}
```

Comment: Geez, we even gave it the same name.

Answer (score 17):

## Swift

```
NSMakeRange(0, str.length)
```

or as an `extension`:

```
extension NSString {
    func fullrange() -> NSRange {
        return NSMakeRange(0, self.length)
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct. But the question is "Shortcut to generate an NSRange for entire length of NSString"

Comment: The question is also about Objective-C. If you use Swift, then also use String.

Comment: `NSString` may be obsolete in Swift, but `NSAttributedString` isn't, and the same code works for it (aside from the class name, obviously).

Answer (score 7):

## Swift 2:

```
extension String {
    var fullRange:Range<String.Index> { return startIndex..<endIndex }
}
```

as in

```
let swiftRange = "abc".fullRange
```

or

```
let nsRange = "abc".fullRange.toRange
```

Comment: For `"abc".fullRange.toRange`, I get the compile time error: "Value of type 'Range<String.Index>' (aka 'Range<String.CharacterView.Index>') has no member 'toRange'." I'm running Xcode 8.3.3 with Swift 3.1.

Answer (score 6):

This is not shorter, but... Oh well

```
NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:str];
```

Comment: Clever. But I hesitate to introduce what could be a lot of CPU work (matching a long string against itself) for the relatively small benefit of a little less typing for me the programmer.

Comment: And you are right, sometimes a little bit more of code makes it more readable and efficient.

Comment: I used this as well and ran into a problem: if your string happens to be empty (@""), you get {NSNotFound, 0}.

Comment: This function only parse valid ranges as `@"{0, 13}"` etc, it will not create `NSRange` for full length of string, if string does not contain valid range, but rather random string, it returns `{0,0}` range. http://nshipster.com/nsrange/